# Can i separate my web hosts from my email hosts?

Tags: email, hosting, web-hosting

Just a simple question really, I was just wondering if it was possible to keep my email hosting with my current provider and move my web host to  a new provider?

Is this possible? If so would there be any issues with it?

Comment: Yes, you can. You just need to point your A record to your old mail server. But why you want to do that? If you separate your mail and hosting, you pay twice, spend more money. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I point my domain to seperate hosts for web and email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457187/how-do-i-point-my-domain-to-seperate-hosts-for-web-and-email)