# How do I point my domain to seperate hosts for web and email

Tags: email, web, hosting, nameservers

I would like find out how to keep my email hosting and domain registered and hosted with 123 reg (my current website host) but point my domain to another host where i want to move my website to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the DNS records to 
1. keep the MX records and naked domain `A` record (`domain.tld` only) - as is
2. Create `A` or `CNAME` records for `www.domain.tld` for the web site subdomain (`www`).

You may point the naked domain to another provider as well, but it might be a bit tricky with some DNS editing interfaces.